# Order By a database field that contains localized data of key and value

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, localization

I have a database table that contains a name string field, In my application i send the a localized name of key and value and save it as a string, the field look like this : `{"en":"Expenses" , "ar": "خصوم", "fr": "Dépenses"}`, i want to build a search query by name but i'll only have one text field to send the input so i get the language from the sent text using regex : `bool isArabic = Regex.IsMatch(request.Name, @"[\u0600-\u06FF]+");`. I want to use a binary serach algorithm to increase performance of serach query instead of using `String.Contains()` In order to use bianry search i have to sort the list depending on the identified language, but when i use `Order By` It only sort the list of names of the`{"en"}` Key. So How can i sort the this list based on the identified language ?

I've Tried converting to Localized Data and assign the key like this `query.ProjectToType<AccountDto>().OrderBy(x => x.Name["en"])` but it didn't work.

Comment: `ProjectToType` seems to be from mapster. Does mapster map from JSON to an object?

Comment: yes i map the name to a localized object ```public LocalizedData Name { get; set; }``` , i tried sorting with key before and after mapping but it didn't work too

Comment: "it didn't work" is not helpful. What did happen? Did you get an error? Which one? Or did it not behave as expected?

Comment: it throws "LINQ expression can't be translated" and returns a zero length list